# Different behavior when PHP script executed through cron job

Tags: php, cron, nohup

I have a script, let's call it mainfile.php that has an include in it for a file in the same directory. I am including it as follows:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once './myincludefile.php';
?>
```

If I do the following:

```
nohup php mainfile.php >/dev/null
```

It runs without any problems. However, if turn this into a cron job, I get the following message (in my mail spool):

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(./myincludefile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/code/mainfile.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './myincludefile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in/home/code/mainfile.php on line 5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When running tasks by cron you have to always specify full path in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the current working directory of the script is not the same when called via cron. (I assume it is `/`, the root directory)

Change the `require_once` to:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/myincludefile.php';
```

[`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) will always contain the directory where the current script is located - not the current working directory. That´s why it is handy to build relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Please change path to absolute path in `require_once './myincludefile.php';`

and run this command as

```
nohup php-q mainfile.php >/dev/null
```